# How to navigate to a special tab in jquerytools tab / slide?

Tags: jquery, tabs, slideshow, jquery-tools

I see no function in [**tabs documentation**](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tabs/index.html), neither in [**slideshow documentation**](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tabs/slideshow.html) to let us manually choose a specific tab / slide.

There ARE `next()` and `prev()`, but not something like a `goTo( slideIndex )`.

---

**UPDATE 1** after [Spokey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18570651/315550):

As I have activated slide change on `mouseover`, the code `$('#accordion img:eq(0)').mouseover();` had to do the trick for me, but it doesn't.

The complete code:

```
$("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div", {
    tabs: 'img.tab',
    effect: 'fade', /*horizontal*/
    event: 'mouseover'
});

$('#accordion').mouseleave(function(){
    // Following line doesn't act
    $('#accordion img:eq(0)').mouseover();
    // While the following alert() states that the selector is ok
    alert($('#accordion img:eq(0)').attr('src'));
})
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

We know that there are some tabs that user can see each one by mouseover. In this place **WHAT EXACTLY I WANT** is that if the user leaves the whole tabs (`div#accordion` in this example), only a special tab (called **default tab**) to be activated. In other words the last active tab should change to the default tab on mouseleave.

Please tell me what exactly should be in `$('#accordion').mouseleave(function(){` and `});`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tools don't seem to have the best documentation, but the slideshow most definitely has a manual slide tab selector.

[image]
From: [the standalone demo](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/slideshow.htm)

For a better view: http://jsfiddle.net/upbzy/3/

```
<!-- the tabs -->
<!-- IMPORTANT BIT -->
<div class="slidetabs"> <a href="#">slide 1</a>
 <a href="#">slide 2 </a>
 <a href="#">slide 3</a>

</div>

  $(function () {
      $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

          // enable "cross-fading" effect
          effect: 'fade',
          fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

          // start from the beginning after the last tab
          rotate: true

          // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
      }).slideshow();

      //added for demo purposes only
      $('.slidetabs a').click( function(){
          $('body').toggleClass('green');
      });
  });
```

**Update:**

I think you may be looking for something like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/upbzy/7/)**

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").tabs("#accordion > div", {
        tabs: 'img.tab',
        effect: 'fade',
        event: 'mouseover'
    });

    $('#accordion').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#accordion img:eq(0)').tabs("#accordion > div");
        $('.tab').first().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, I updated the question. That is the exact problem that I have.

Comment: @MohammadNaji I'm not sure I know what you mean... can you explain in a little more detail?

Comment: Thank you. I exactly want that after sees some tabs, if he leaves the mouse the whole tabs, only the first tab be activated. In other words when the mouse leaves the tabs, the active tab should change to the first tab.

Comment: Question explained at UPDATE 2. Sorry if that was ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found one either but a workaround would be to trigger the click event manually.

For tabs something like

```
$('.box .tabs li:eq(0) a').click()
```

NOTE: The tabs API seems to have some sort of `click(index)` method

And for the slideshow you click on the pagination

```
$('.slidetabs a:eq(0)').click()
```

In the above example you give the index of the slide/tab in `:eq()`

Comment: I wouldn't think that such a solution could be usable. Thank you for the idea. But it doesn't yet work (q updated)

Comment: @MohammadNaji can you please create a fiddle showing your code?

Comment: I've uploaded the template to http://upservers.ir/websites/miu-graduated/second-template/ Please look at the 3 vertical tabs at left.